# Export of locally available Docker image to local file system

Tags: docker

Is it possible:

- export of locally available image to local file system ?
- import of local file of image to local docker repository, which is not available before the operation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `docker save yournamespace/yourimage:label > image.tar.gz` to save your image to a local `tar.gz` file.

You can then re-import it and set a new tag pointing to your repository with `cat yourimage.tar.gz | docker import - yourrepository:5000/yournamespace/yourimage:label`.

Then you can push it to your local docker repository called `repository` with a simple `docker push yourrepository:5000/yournamespace/yourimage:label`.

**EDIT**: Keep in mind that volumes are not included in the `tar.gz` file!